# How to wait for all observable to complete and store the result in an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Levels object is an collection of different measures at each level of soil.Each level has a set of key value pairs(K,N,P), where the value is the id of a sensor type.

I need to call the api for each of the unit, for all four levels by calling drillData method which takes sensorType id as an argument and wait for all the observable to complete and store the result(sum of the total in SensorData) in exact same format replacing the sensor type id with the total. How do I achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance.

```js
   export interface SensorData {
       period?:string,
       total?:number
   }

  public drillData(params?: {}):Observable<SensorData[]> {
        return this._http
          .get(this.url + "drill_data/", {
            headers: FapAPIRequestOptions.withTokenHeaders,
            params,
          }).pipe(map((r:Response)=>r["This year"] as SensorData[] ));
   }



 public levelValues: SoilLevels = {
    level30: {},
    level15: {},
    level10: {},
    level5: {},
  };

const levels={
level5: {K: 86, N: 84, P: 85, ec: 53, ph: 55, humidity: 38, temperature: 37}
level10: {K: 86, N: 84, P: 85, ec: 53, ph: 55, humidity: 38, temperature: 35}
level15: {K: 86, N: 84, P: 85, ec: 53, ph: 55, humidity: 57, temperature: 37}
level30: {K: 86, N: 84, P: 85, ec: 53, ph: 55, humidity: 93, temperature: 92}
}

for (let level of Object.keys(levels)) {
        for (let sensorKey of Object.keys(levels[level])) {
          try {
            const sensorData = await this.sensorService
              .drillData({ ...this.params, sensor: levels[level][sensorKey] })
              .toPromise();
            let total = 0;
            for (let data of sensorData) {
              total += data.total;
            }
            this.levelValues[level][sensorKey] = total;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      }
```

I have used toPromise() here, but it waits for the previous request to complete to fire the next request. Is there any other to call all the observables in parallel and store them in this.levelValues once they all are complete.

This is the data sample that I get from Api

endpoint : drill_data/?from=2018-09-15T10:56:40.005Z&to=2021-09-15T10:56:40.005Z&agg_by=all&sensor=92

This is the response from the api

```js
"This year":[
{period: "2021-09-14T12:15:14Z", total: 10},
{period: "2021-09-14T12:15:38Z", total: 12}
]
```

Comment: What will be sensorId while calling drillData method

Comment: sesnorId is the value of the key in each levels which I provided.

Comment: I did not understand this `the result(sum of the total in SensorData) in exact same format replacing the sensor type id with the total.`

Comment: The object which I provided in the question contains sensor id(86,84,....). For each of this id i'll make a api call using the drill data function. The api returns an array of objects in the shape of SensorData. I'll have to get the value from the SensorData and place that in the object which has the exact same shape of the levels object, but this time instead of the id, i'll place the value which I got from the api

Comment: Will you Please share sample input to `drillData` from levels, and the response you will get from it and the operation you want to perform on it.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more details. @NavnathJadhav

Comment: So here `{K: 86, N: 84, P: 85, ec: 53, ph: 55, humidity: 38, temperature: 37}`  7 API call will be made? like wise are you going to make 28 API calls?

Comment: Yes you are right. There are four levels so there will be totally 28 api calls.

Comment: But let's consider you made an API call for `K:86` of `level5` and again you made API call for `K:86` of `level10` aren't their response will be the same?

Comment: [This is how this soil widget is created.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088231/how-to-structure-or-build-form-for-the-repetitive-set-of-fields-in-angular-10). Users select the sensors for each level. Sometimes they may have same value. But I am open to suggestions if there is any better way to avoid repeating the same api calls with same values

Comment: We can make it in 11 API calls instead of 28. Performance will be much greater.

Comment: Could you please post an answer. That would be great

Comment: What will be the input to this `public drillData(params?: {})` just IDs: 86, 85, 84.. right?

Comment: along with from and to date. like this {from:date,to:date,sensor:86}

Comment: From where we will get  values of `from` and `to`

Comment: Just use new Date() constructor

Comment: Is this your sample expected output `level10 {
K: 300
N: 700
P: 1000
ec: 200
humidity: 200
ph: 400
temperature: 20 }`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a very clever native operator for this, but I don't know it.
But at least, you could do it sequentially like this :

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

let output = {}

for( let key of Object.keys(levels)){
    output[key] = await lastValueFrom( drillData(levels[key]) )
}

console.log(output);
```

EDIT

I guess the "native and clever" method I was mentioning is [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest). You can attempt something like this :

```
const observables:Observable<SensorData[]>[] = Object.values(levels).map(drillData.bind(this));

let result:any = {};

combineLatest(observables)
    .subscribe( drilled => {
        Object.keys(levels).forEach( (key, index) => result[key] = drilled[index] )
    })
```

Comment: lastValueFrom is available only in version 7 of rxjs library. Can I use toPromise in version 6

Comment: Using promise really takes long time for all the api calls to get complete. I need this observable to run parallelly and return the result when all observables are complete. Is there anyway?

Comment: Promises don't take longer than Observables. You can run them in parallel instead of sequentially using `Promise.all`

Comment: If it is possible could you please demonstrate it in your answer. That would be helpful

Comment: Yes, answer updated, but this is absolutely untested, just a guess or a hint

Comment: Levels binding has four more levels, here you used Object.values(levels) which returns a object but not a value

Comment: What? `Object.values` return an array of objects. Then I pass each object to `drillData`, which returns an Observable for each object passed, so we get an array of Observables. Finally I group everything inside `combineLatest`. What's the problem?

Comment: No the drill data accepts only the id not the entire object, drillData({from:date,to:date,sensor:"Here goes the id"})

Answer (score 0):

Use forkJoin

```
forkJoin(
  yourRequest1(),
  yourRequest2(),
  yourRequest3()
).subscribe(totalResult => console.log('After completing all observables',totalResult);
```

You can get result of your each request by following below code in this case.

totalResult[0]

totalResult[1]

totalResult[2]

Comment: What if `levels` contains 30 entries, as it seems to be the case? (There's a key named "level30") Also, what's `yourRequest1()` ?

Comment: yourRequest1() means your observable no 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of using this

```
const sensorData = await this.sensorService.drillData({ ...this.params,sensor: levels[level][sensorKey] }).toPromise();
```

> Use this

```
const sensorData =forkJoin({
    this.sensorService.drillData({ ...this.params, sensor: levels[level][sensorKey] })
})
.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

> Refer this :
> https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: The doc says we need to provide a key inside forkJoin. I have different levels, how do I structure them?

Comment: Not necessary. If you pass the key it will more easy for you to get the result of whichever observable you want(by using a key). If you do not use the key it will give you an array of objects, in the same sequence as you are passing observable.(I already gave you an example below totalResult[0])

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with creating a request for each nested key. We will create an array of requests for each object inside the `levels` object.

```
from = new Date();
to = new Date();
finalResult$: Observable<any>; // to hold all final response

const requests = Object.keys(this.levels).map(key => this.toRequest(key));

toRequest(key: string): any[] {
    return Object.keys(this.levels[key]).map(K => ({
      sensorValue: this.levels[key][K],
      level: key,
      sensorKey: K,
      to: this.to,
      from: this.from
    }));
  }
```

Since we have an array of requests we will flatMap them using [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)
Then we will use [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) to make parallel API requests.
When we get a response, we will use [reduce](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) to calculate the total value and place them inside the result according to their level.

Note that [reduce](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) will only emit one final value, only when the source Observable completes.

```
const levels$ = from(requests);

this.finalResult$ = levels$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(requestArr => requestArr),
    mergeMap(request => this.drillData(request)),
    reduce((acc, item) => this.responseReducer(acc, item), {}),
    catchError(x => of({}))
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });

// method to reduce responses into final required level object
responseReducer(acc, { level, sensorKey, sensorData }): any {
    const sum = this.getTotal(sensorData);
    const sensor = { [sensorKey]: sum };

    // if example `level15` key is already exists in accumulator
    //  we will  copy previous level data combined with current sensor data
    if (acc[level]) {
      acc = { ...acc, [level]: { ...acc[level], ...sensor } };
    } else {
      // if not we will just add into accumulator
      acc = { ...acc, [level]: sensor };
    }
    return acc;
}

public getTotal(sensorData: SensorData[]): number {
    return sensorData.reduce((acc, { total }) => (acc += total), 0);
}
```

At the time of making API requests, we will maintain an object which will keep track of already make requests and their responses, so that if the request is already made we will return the response from the cache.

```
const cachedResponse = this.getCache(uniqueKey);
const responseMetaData = { level, sensorKey, sensorValue };
if (cachedResponse) {
  return of({ sensorData: cachedResponse, ...responseMetaData });
}
```

To print response

```
<pre>
  {{ this.finalResult$ | async | json }}
</pre>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2bhlwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the demo, you will get the below payload in the `params` in the `drillData` method. Just you need to make use of appropriate parameters to make an API call.

```
{
    from: "2021-09-15T16:01:54.297Z",
    level: "level5",
    sensorKey: "K",
    sensorValue: 86,
    to: "2021-09-15T16:01:54.297Z",
}
```

Below is the dummy API call I have made in `drillData`, you just need to replace `of` with your actual API call

```
return of(this.tempResponse[sensorValue]).pipe(
      tap(response => this.setCache(uniqueKey, response)),
      map(sensorData => ({ sensorData, ...responseMetaData }))
    );
```

Let me know if anything is missing.